# android studio variables en la ultima versión

Tags: android-studio, condiciones

Necesito crear una variable con una fecha que yo asigne y compararlo con la fecha actual del dispositivo y comparar si es igual y mostrar un mensaje con android studio.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {




    int count = 1;
    int count2 = 2;
    int count3 = 5;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);




        Thread t = new Thread() {


            @Override
            public void run() {

                while (!isInterrupted()) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);  //1000ms = 1 sec

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                          @Override
                                          public void run() {

                                              TextView tdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                                              long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                              SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-AA");
                                              String dateString = sdf.format(date);
                                              tdate.setText(dateString);


                                              String dateInString = "2019";
                                              Date fecha = null;
                                              try {
                                                  fecha = sdf.parse(dateInString);
                                              } catch (ParseException e) {
                                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                              }
                                              long dateInTimeStamp = fecha.getTime();




                                              if (dateInString==dateInString){
                                                  textView.setText("evento inicio");








                                          }

                                      }






                        );

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
    }


    public void button(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void startActivities(Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué quieres hacer eso, es para controlar las versiones o algo así? Eso se puede controlar desde el `gradle`... cuidado si llevas un mes tratando de reinventar algo que ya existe ¿? ¿Podrías decir cuál es la finalidad de hacer esto?

Comment: no ,,es un trabajo y no encuentro la forma... lo que quiero es que yo guarde una fecha en una variable en string  pero  la variable no la debe pedir , ya debe estar por defecto , es decir es una fecha fija y la otra variable que me la traiga del sistema android  y  la convierta en un string y las compare  y me muestre un mensaje que las dos fechas son iguales necesito ayuda , se los agradezco , si hay otro método también lo recibo que tenga el mismo resultado

Comment: Deberías añadir el código con lo que has intentado.  Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]